# Boosting parts of a query with Solr

Tags: regex, solr, lucene

I am developing a set of queries to find a canonical product description, from a free text input. Consider the following examples that illustrate my problem:

```
(* Where: (a) Free text (b) Should have returned (c) What was found)

 - (a) 'CUTTER FLOOR90 CM DUPLEX - IRWIN' 
 - (b) 'CUTTER F/FLOOR/AZULEJ.90CM DUPLEX  0096'
 - (c) 'CUTTER FLOOR65 CM DUPLEX - IRWIN'
 - (a) 'WELDABLE GLOVE 50MM - TIGER'
 - (b) 'LUVA . WELD BROWN 826 TIGER(50MM)' 
 - (c) 'WELDABLE GLOVE 40MM - TIGER'
 - (a) 'INSULATION TAPE 33+ SCOTCH 19X10M - 3M'
 - (b) 'INSUL. TAPE.PVC PT  19MMX10M  N.33+ H00018' 
 - (c) 'INSULATION TAPE HIGHLAND 19X05M - 3M'
 - (a) 'KEY COMBINATION 14MM - GEDORE'
 - (b) 'KEY COMB. 14MM    CV. 002509  002509 1' 
 - (c) 'KEY COMBINATION 10MM - GEDORE'
```

As you can see, the query returned the string that matched more closely as a whole. I need to boost the importance of substrings such as (\d+)MM or (\d+)CM.

How would you go about this, preferably with Solr?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to issue different queries based on the 2 scenarios you are facing.

For helping you with cases 1 and 3, where the query does not contain the regexes, you can keep an extra field in your documents, say called `popularity`. Keep it higher for documents with the regexes. Then just follow what the Solr [relevancy page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29) says.

For cases 2 and 4, where the query itself contains the regexes, you can issue a query with extra boost for the matching terms.